# Is possible to a generator function return other types instead of generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, cpython

I want to know how python checks for return type on a generator function.

I developed a function that yields from a list, then when the list is empty it simply returns None

Example:

```py
def my_function(i):
    if i == 1:
        return
    else:
        yield from [1,2,3]
```

I tested, and even if the parameter `i` is set to `1`, the return will always be a generator, even if the yield wasn't evaluated.

This is the behaviour that I expected but I thought it could return a None type, now I want to understand why.

```py
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: import inspect

In [3]: def my_function(i):
   ...:     if i == 1:
   ...:         return
   ...:     else:
   ...:         yield from [1,2,3]
   ...: 

In [4]: dis.dis(my_function)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

  5     >>   12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             18 BUILD_LIST               3
             20 GET_YIELD_FROM_ITER
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 YIELD_FROM
             26 POP_TOP
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE

In [5]: inspect.isgeneratorfunction(my_function)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: type(my_function(1))
Out[6]: generator

In [7]: type(my_function(None))
Out[7]: generator
```

I imagine that python do some code verification, but I didn't understand how this works when reading the cpython code.

Comment: Containing a `yield` statement makes it a generator function, even if the `yield` is never encountered. Whether or not to run it as a generator can't be determined after the function is already in progress.

Comment: A `yield` **anywhere** in the definition makes it a generator function, at which point a `return` just stops the generator, like rasing `StopIteration`